# Deep merging objects with the spread operator

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I can merge multiple objects like this:

```
  var a = {k:{i:1, j:2}, m:6}
  var b = {k:{i:3, l:4}}
  var c = {
    ...a,
    ...b
  }
```

`c` has `m:6` which is good; however, c doesn't contain `k.j:2`. That's because `...b` did a shallow overwrite.

I'd like to use `...` recursively so that nested properties not in `b` don't get over-written.

I like `...` because it's so fast and clean looking. Can I do that in `c`'s object initializer?

---

**Update**

I got this close so far but it seems kinda verbose:

```
  var merge = (a,b) => Object.assign(a, ...Object.keys(b).map(k => ({[k]: typeof b[k] === 'object' ? merge(a[k], b[k]) : b[k]})))
  var a = {k:{i:1, j:2}, m:6}
  var b = {k:{i:3, l:4}}
  var c = merge(a,b)
```

Comment: This seems like a good `reduce` scenario... Do you have to worry about functions at all or just strings/numbers? Also are you looking to do this inline or would a dedicated function suffice?

Comment: @Dom, no functions. Just objects and data. I have created `var m = (a,b) => ({...a,...Object.keys(b).reduce((acc,p) => {acc[p] = typeof b[p] === 'object' ? m(a[p], b[p]) : b[p];return acc;}, {})})` so I can `c = m(a,b)` , and that works, but I'm trying to shorten it by making it more inline. Seems like `{...}` could replace `reduce`, but I'm trying to see how :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`Object.assign(a,b)` gives the desired result.

However, it is possible to deep merge objects with the [spread operator](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp) like this if you recursively apply the spread operator all the way down. I'm pretty sure this is what `Object.assign` does.

This listing is still too verbose for my liking.

```js
const isObject = (v) => v && typeof v === 'object'
const merge = (a,b) => ({...Object.keys(b).reduce((_,k)=>(_[k]=isObject(b[k])?merge(a[k],b[k]):b[k],_),a)})
    
var a = {m:1, n:2, o:3, p:4, r:{s:5, t:6}}
var b = {m:7, o:8, r:{s:9, u:10, v:null}}
var c = merge(a,b)
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible using `...`. If you know in advance the shape of your objects though you could write:

```js
  var a = {k:{i:1, j:2}, m:6}
  var b = {k:{i:3, l:4}}
  var c = {
    ...a,
    ...b,
    k: { ...a.k, ...b.k },
  }
```

Otherwise, you'll need to write a function to do it or search for one: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=merge+deep

Comment: um, no it's not impossible. It just requires the spread operator to be a recursive function rather than an object reference. See my answer.

Comment: Your question asks if it's possible with the spread operator. It is not. Therefore it is impossible.
Also your answer contains an bug, because `typeof null === 'object'`.